# Trying to read data from a txt

Tags: c++

I am very new to programming and have learned HTML, Javascript, and java so far. Right now I am teaching myself C++ which I am very new to.

I am working on loading in and reading a .txt file.
In my .txt files I have floats and characters, I am trying to read in the floats and if a character is read the program needs to stop reading in the rest of the file.

so far I have this

```
#include<iostream> 
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
ifstream DaFl("file1.txt");
}
```

Is there anything like java's scanner class like nextint or next that will read the line of the txt file? I have a pretty good idea on testing using if and while I just do not know how to pull one line from the txt file.

Comment: Learn to search first.  Using keywords "c++ read text struct" will give you a lot of examples.  This should be closed as a duplicate of something.

Comment: *Right now I am teaching myself C++ which I am very new to.* -- Don't use Java as a model in trying to figure out how C++ works.  Get yourself a good  C++ book and assume Java, Javascript, etc. doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably one of the more common questions in c++ and if you did a simple search you could find the answer in a variety of ways.

```
   string line;
   ifstream myfile ("example.txt");

   if (myfile.is_open())
   {
       while ( getline (myfile,line) )
       { 
           cout << line << '\n';
       }

      myfile.close();
  }
```

Comment: And after you have read a single line with `std::getline()`, you can use a `std::istringstream` to read values from that line.

Comment: I have tried this using eclipse and whenever I use .is_open or .open I get an  error no method. Do i have to create my own method for these?

Comment: Sounds like your not including fstream.  Try adding #include <fstream>